# How to find in text all word with specific ending?

Tags: regex

I need to find in text all words with specific ending.
example
APPWIN/DOW - APPWIN - mandatory part. DOW - optional part

Word may be only mandatory part or mandatory part + any number of letters from optional part in same sequence.

Regex should find these words: APPWIN, APPWIND, APPWINDO, APPWINDOW.
But these words must be ignored: APPWINDOWS, APPWINO, APPWINA.

I tried to use groups, but i am confused them...

Comment: APPWINDOWS why should this be ignored if DOW is optional?

Comment: At the end of the word should be only optional part.

Comment: `APPWIN(D(O(W)?)?)?\b` should do it. Show us the groups that you tried!

Comment: @Bergi......This will not pass APPWIN/DOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?=.*?APPWIN$|.*?APPWIN.*?D$|.*?APPWIN.*?DO$|.*?APPWIN.*?DOW$).*
```

This works . A lookahead for all the conditions.
http://regex101.com/r/bT1oA6/1